# Translate VB.NET "Await" to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, async-await

I'm trying to find the C# equivalent of this VB.NET line:

`Dim paymentResponse As PaymentResponse = Await paymentClient.CreatePaymentAsync(paymentRequest)`

I tried a few codetranslators like https://converter.telerik.com/ and https://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/

But none of them seem to return valid C# syntax, e.g.

`PaymentResponse paymentResponse = Await; /* TODO ERROR: Skipped SkippedTokensTrivia *//* TODO ERROR: Skipped SkippedTokensTrivia */`

How should I translate the above line to C#?

Comment: "But none of them seem to return valid C# syntax." - what did they return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`var paymentResponse = await paymentClient.CreatePaymentAsync(paymentRequest);`